# Avoid google oauth2 client secret in code

Tags: c, oauth-2.0

I'm writing a small c program which connects to the google api via Oauth2.
Therefore I need to send a client secret to google.
I store this secret in my code, which I want to push to github, but how can I avoid to show my client secret to everybody who looks at my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a configuration file where you'll store the API key... you have many options, the simplest being writing the key directly into the file, more sophisticated being using some kind of serializers (like json, xml, inifile etc...), the right option is up to you (usually, you'll want to serialize if you want to store several options in the file).

You can also set the key as a program argument, if you don't mind the key to be visible in the process list of your host.

And be sure not to push your already existing git history to git hub, but create a new repository, or all your previous patches (with the key) will be public ;)

Comment: Thank you, I think the solution with the file will do the trick for now:-)

Answer (score 2):

Storing secret (and ideally any string literals) in code is wrong - store it in a resource (text) file and don't push it to Git.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for ***where to find out your Client Secret*** for your Google Drive apss. then follow this step.

1. Go to your project
2. Click Credential.

> After that you will get all the details about your project like *client
>   id, redirect uri* etc. But there you will click on button "**Download
>   Jason**" and after downloading a file you will get your CLIENT SECRET.
>   Please look at the picture.

[image]